# I need hack together an editable Crosstab for a Form

Tags: ms-access, vba

I have a situation where I want to simplify data entry.  The table is 12 months long and will have about 6 or 7 rows of depth.  I'm rather new to MS Access so I thought I would be clever and just throw a Crosstab Query into a form.  Worked great until I realized you can't edit it!!!

Fine, I'll just draw out 72 text boxes and link them to the right rows.  Well it looked pretty but then I found out that each row is a record and thus only one of my beautiful boxes was populating.

Does anyone have any hacks or methods that can get the cross tab look?

I considered the idea of having 72 subforms, but that would be really messy and probably slow everything down (nevermind seeming downright silly).

I also pondered about throwing a bunch of DLOOKUP's at it, but that wouldn't be editable anyway and I might as well just use the standard crosstab.

Thanks!

Comment: Once you group records into a single row either by a crosstab query or a group by as you state this will always be read-only perhaps you can look at redesigning the table to make the data entry easier

Comment: It's not terribly complex but I need to design for the lowest common d.  A crazy idea I had would be to export it into excel then, somehow, import it back in...

Comment: You could use a datasheet - it would probably work, though it's not necessarily that pretty. Alternatively, you could use the form you already created, but you'd need to retrieve the data programmatically and display it on the form, and also manage the saving of the data after the user's made any changes to it, also programmatically (ie without relying on access's data binding and persistence capabilities)